# Google Chrome keyword search is no longer working

Tags: google-chrome, search, keyword

I have been using [keyword search](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-set-keyword-bookmarks-in-google-chrome-5476033) in Google Chrome for a long time. But today, after an update (to Version 88.0.4324.150 (Official Build) (64-bit) running under Microsoft Windows 10), the use of a search keywords now just searches both for the keyword and the words to the right of it in my default search engine (currently DuckDuckGo), and not the web page in that configured search engine.

Below are my settings for the current version of Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome settings]

Using "ab testing" should search askubuntu.com for "testing", not duckduckgo, but this is what results:

[image: ab testing bad search result]

I cannot use another browser such as Firefox for unrelated reasons.

Did Google break this functionality? And, how do I find a fix for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `chrome://flags` and disable the "Omnibox suggestion button row" (`chrome://flags/#omnibox-suggestion-button-row`).

[image]

Comment: I just had chrome updated and this was the very first thing I noticed... I was like "oh hell no!" hah.

Comment: I would *never* ever had found that item buried deep into the "flags". Extremely helpful, as my work productivity is now saved! Thank you!

Comment: It looks like they reverted it back to the old behavior where it defaults back to your configured search engine so this may no longer be necessary (as of 89.0.4389.90).